# Android - Apply a bitmap texture to API drawing routines

Tags: android, textures, android-canvas, porter-duff

I have a bitmap that spans the whole screen that will function as texture for a Path object that I need to draw to my canvas. I then have a background image that this textured path needs to be drawn on top of.

I tried using the PorterDuff modes, but nothing seemed to work correctly. I was having a hard time figuring out exactly how the PorterDuff modes act, because none of them seem to act the way [I always thought they were supposed to function](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/).

I've figured out a way to texture the path with this test code:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
    //draw the texture
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.texture),0,0,paint);
   //construct the Path with an inverse even-odd fill
Path p = new Path();
p.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);
p.addCircle(this.getHeight()/2, this.getWidth()/2, 200, Path.Direction.CCW);
   //use CLEAR to remove inverted fill, thus showing only the originally filled section
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
   //draw path
canvas.drawPath(p, paint);
```

But I can't figure out how to then place that on top of a background image. Am I just using the PorterDuff modes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my questions could lead you to your solution:

The `paint` used in your `drawPath` call:
What is the paint style?
What is the paint stroke width?
What is the paint stroke/fill color?

If you are not using a stoke/fill color, but a texture instead, where is the call to the paint's `setShader` (using a `BitmapShader`)?

Comment: The style is fill, and that's the only part that matters there, because you shouldn't ever see the fill color or strokes. I would use a BitmapShader, but I don't know of any way to modify the coordinates of the texture to align it the way I want it to be. Is there a way that I do not know of?